# Recalculate pagination on first item after changing the amount of items

Tags: php, pagination

I have a list of 100 products that are subdivided in groups of 10 items by default. So my pagination has 10 pages of 10 items. The user can choose if there will be 10 or 20 items are displayed in the list.

Now I want that if a user on page 3 switched from 10 to 20 items the pagination is recalculated based on the current first item of page 3.

The pagination will now always starts again on page 1 after switching between the quantity of items.

Unfortunately I can not figure out what the best calculation for this is.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a Class `Paginator` with a method `getData($limit, $page)`.

Regarding the selection of the user, a `$_GET` or `$_POST` parameter of the current `$page` and the desired `$limit` is given to the `getData($limit, $page)` Method.

Then I would read the **desired number of rows** from the DB and store it in a `$result`. *(Always start with last **item id** and limit it to the count of rows the user wants to see.. Like `limit 30` in SQL, if the user wants to see 30 rows)*

After that, read out the id of the last row you just pulled from the DB (**last item** of `$result`). Store that id in a var like `$lastid`. Now you start with the `$lastid` you just received from the last item of the `$result` array. And pull the next 30 items from the DB.

I would store the pages in a **multidimensional array**.

```
$pages = array("0"=>array(item1, item2, ... item30),"1"=>array(item31, item32, ... item 60), ...)
```

That gives you a structure like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => item1
            [1] => item2
            [2] => item3
            ...
            [29] => item30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => item31
            [1] => item32
            ...
            [29] => item60
        )
)
```

To display the items I wold then simply use a foreach loop to generate the page tabs.

```
foreach($pages as $page_number => $items){
    /* Your code */
}
```

I hope that's going help you :)